# Spring-insight source, design and alternatives

Tags: tcserver, spring-insight

I've a few questions regarding the Spring-insight technology.

- Is Spring-insight open source? I was curious to see the underlying design. I could fine the plugins' source but not the entire package (is it part of tc-server).
- Can this data be persisted to a database (for later use)
- I read that Spring insight should not be used for production use. I was thinking if this data could be persisted to some datastore and retrieved through a different application. Are there any existing alternatives to Spring insight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Spring-insight open source? I was curious to see the underlying
>   design. I could fine the plugins' source but not the entire package
>   (is it part of tc-server).

As of me writing this, Spring Insight itself is not open source, but the Spring Insight Plugins are released under the ASL 2.0 license.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-insight-plugins

> Can this data be persisted to a database (for later use)

Data is saved internal to Spring Insight and is retained for a period of time (which is configurable).  After that period, it is purged from the system.  I believe 7 days is the default.  There is no way at the moment to persist this data to an external system such as a MySQL or Oracle Database.

> I read that Spring insight should not be used for production use.

This is old information.  Originally Spring Insight was released as a developer-only tool, called Spring Insight for Developers.  As the name suggests, this tool should only be used in development or possibly small QA environments.  This tool can be obtained for free (as in beer) from here.

http://www.springsource.org/insight

For production use, you would want to use Spring Insight Operations.  This is a commercial product which is available as a part of the VMware vFabric Product suite or by purchasing vFabric tc Server.